# Export all Custom Metadata Types details in csv

Tags: metadata-api, administration, custom-metadata

Recently took over the instance as admin.

Previous instance is managed by an outsourced development team. There are 3 picklists that are controlled by custom metadata types and apex trigger. Not fully understand why they have to do it that way.

I am using a custom metadata loader to bulk update picklist values. Before that, I'd like to export all the custom metadata values like namespace, label, field api names. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

It's just like any other object you'd want to export. Use the Data Loader, Excel Connector, the Workbench, or any other data export tool you might have, select the data, and export. I'd probably recommend the workbench, as it requires no extra software. Just go to the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/), log in to your org via Workbench, choose queries > SOQL queries from the main menu, select the object, fields, any criteria you want, and check the Bulk CSV option. After running, click the blue download icon to get your CSV file. If there's a lot of data, it may appear in multiple chunks (multiple CSV files).